# Node syntax error on linux but not window

Tags: node.js, linux, syntax

I have an issue with a node server, it work fine on windows,and used it and worked with it for a while, but on linux (it's the same, it's a git clone, and the same server work fine on macOs too) it throws a syntax error like this:
[The error on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHg5m.png)
Do you have any idea on how i can fix it? Since the code works fine on two different OS

Thanks in advance
Maxime
A lost student

Comment: Probably because shorthand object properties aren't supported on your platform.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, congrats on your first question and on accepting the answer! As a side-note, have a look at the preview panel before posting to see what your question will look like when submitted, and try to avoid links to external websites if possible when describing your next issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your nodejs versions, looks like you running older version at ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, i thought i installed the last version but seems not, i am not that pro with linux hehe